# Django Model - Abstract Class with Self Relationship

Tags: python, django, inheritance, database-design, data-modeling

I'm trying to design a forum thread in Django. Users can post threads, replies to threads, or replies to other thread replies (like in Reddit comments). All posts share basic info like the date and author so I thought I'd make an abstract `Post` class. Since all posts can have a `parent` post which they are replying to, my intuition was to try and define it on the abstract class:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True)
    createdBy = models.ForeignKey(User)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Thread(Post):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ThreadReply(Post):
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

But the result is that the child class can only have a parent of the same type, while a `ThreadReply` should really be able to have a parent that is a `Thread` OR a parent that is a `ThreadReply`.
One solution is if I define both relationships in `ThreadReply`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    createdBy = models.ForeignKey(User)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Thread(Post):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ThreadReply(Post):
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    parentThread = models.ForeignKey(Thread,null=True)
    parentReply = models.ForeignKey(ThreadReply,null=True)
```

But that doesn't feel...object-oriented enough? It bothers me that every `ThreadReply` object will have one wasted relationship, as functionally it can only be a replying to a `Thread`, or a `ThreadReply`.

Comment: Have a look at [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)

Comment: Yeah generic relations seem to be the way, thanks. I'll update the post with my generic relation solution when i get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dahrens comment I looked into [Generic Relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) and found what I needed. It did involve changing the inheritance such that the parent class is no longer abstract:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey,GenericRelation
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    createdBy = models.ForeignKey(User)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    parent = GenericForeignKey(content_type,object_id)
    replies = GenericRelation('Post')

class Thread(Post):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Now Post is used for thread replies and the thread itself just extends it. Post has a polymorphic 'parent' relationship which can accept a `Thread` OR a `Post`.